# How to speed up Select with MemberQ for large lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

I have two large lists: list1 and list2. I would like to select elements of list1 only if they appear in list2. Since the list1 has dimensions of (335000, 2) and list2 : (122000, 4), it's taking a very long time.

How could I speed up the process?

```
Select[list1, MemberQ[list2[[All, 2]], #[[1]]] &]
```

Comment: [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.html)?

Comment: well Intersection helps but doesn't quite do it because I want to keep the whole element, not only the key that is to be found in list2...

Comment: One should not have to decode your code to figure out format of lists - please add some simple list1/2 examples.

Comment: @ciao would you consider adding examples yourself, please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @ciao I am referencing your comment above; it would be nice to have explicit examples for `list1` and `list2` to make the code in the question self-contained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be pretty snappy:

```
With[{t = First@Transpose@#1, t2 = Transpose[#2][[2]]}, 
   Pick[#1, Replace[t, Dispatch[Thread[Rule[Intersection[t, t2], True]]], {1}]]] &[list1, list2]
```

Comment: thanks ciao, it is really fast!

Comment: What would I have change where if I wanted to match column 2 of list1 with column 3 of list2?

Comment: @Cancan: `...Transpose[#1][[2]], t2 = Transpose[#2][[3]]...`, etc.

Comment: @Cancan: Or perhaps more useful : `With[{t = Transpose[#1][[#3]], t2 = Transpose[#2][[#4]]}, 
   Pick[#1, 
    Replace[t, 
     Dispatch[
      Thread[Rule[Intersection[t, t2], 
        True]]], {1}]]] &[list1, list2, 2, 3]` - so this has last two arguments being the cols. for lists 1/2... this form also can be used obviously for any size sublists pair of lists...

Comment: Thanks, this form is great! I tried to use it for selection based on 2 columns together but it didn't work: ...`[list1, list2, {1,2},{2,4}]`, what would you recommend?

Also, I tried to use it for selection based on a `! MemberQ` pattern but it didn't work, how would you do it with this form?

Comment: @Cancan:As you've noted, the form optimized for need for speed (implied by OP) is not multi-column aware, nor arbitrary operation aware - probably best to do a new question if you need a generalized "join" (as in database style) operation....

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps not the fastest, but reasonably fast (requires V10+):

```
Select[Association[Thread[list2[[All, 2]] -> True]] @* First][list1]
```

A slightly slower version of this to use for earlier versions:

```
With[{rules = Dispatch[Thread[list2[[All, 2]] -> True]]},
   Select[list1, Replace[First[#], rules] &]
]
```

Comment: thanks but I use V9... :(

Comment: @Cancan I updated the answer with code that should work for you.

Comment: This was similar to my option!.. I lost by few minutes. :) +1

Comment: thanks Leonid! it works but it is not as fast than ciao's answer, which is why I accepted his answer.

Comment: @Cancan Sure, it is always proper to accept the best answer. I voted for that one, too.

Answer (score 3):

One can make use of [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) for this purpose *(I should mention that the speed improvement may only occur in M11.1+)*. Here is a function that does this:

```
carl[l1_,l2_] := With[{nf = Nearest[l2[[All, 2]] -> "Index"]},
    Pick[
        l1,
        Unitize[Length /@ nf[l1[[All, 1]], {All, 0}]],
        1
    ]
]
```

The key idea is the use of the `{All, 0}` spec for the [`NearestFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestFunction) `nf`, that only returns a result for exact hits. Let's compare this to @ciao's approach (modified to be a function):

```
ciao[l1_, l2_] := With[{t = First@Transpose@l1, t2 = Transpose[l2][[2]]},
    Pick[
        l1,
        Replace[t, Dispatch[Thread[Rule[Intersection[t, t2],True]]], {1}]
    ]
]

data1 = RandomInteger[10^6, {335000,2}];
data2 = RandomInteger[10^6, {122000,4}];

r1 = ciao[data1, data2]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = carl[data1, data2]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.41, Null}
>
> {0.17, Null}
>
> True

So, a speed up of about 2.5.

**Update**

After further thought, it makes sense to apply [`NearestFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestFunction) to the other data list. So, here is a version that uses this approach:

```
carl2[l1_, l2_] := With[{nf = Nearest[l1[[All,1]]->"Index"]},
    l1[[Union @@ nf[l2[[All, 2]], {All, 0}]]]
]
```

Here is another speed comparison:

```
data1 = RandomInteger[10^6, {335000,2}];
data2 = RandomInteger[10^6, {122000,4}];

r1 = ciao[data1, data2]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = carl[data1, data2]; //RepeatedTiming
r3 = carl2[data1, data2]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.37, Null}
>
> {0.17, Null}
>
> {0.10, Null}
>
> True

A nice speed up!

Comment: Nice. +1 $\phantom{}$