# How to perform multi-columns selection and/or !MemberQ on large lists with speed?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

This question (2 subquestions) is connected to [How to speed up Select with MemberQ for large lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85316/how-to-speed-up-select-with-memberq-for-large-lists/85349?noredirect=1#comment233360_85349)

Q1: I would like to have an alternate version of the form below to do a multi-columns selection on large data sets. Speed is still very important. 
I tried to do ...`&[list1, list2, {1,3}, {2,3}]` and `With[{t = Transpose[#1][[#3,#4]]`... but I wasn't successful

Q2: Also, I would like to use the form for a pattern similar to `! MemberQ`. 
I tried ...`,False]]]` but nothing happened. I am kind of clueless how I should go about this one..

Form:
`With[{t = Transpose[#1][[#3]], t2 = Transpose[#2][[#4]]}, Pick[#1, Replace[t, Dispatch[ Thread[Rule[Intersection[t, t2], True]]], {1}]]] &[list1, list2, 2, 3]`

Any tipp is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do for part 1 ( so in this example, returns list 1 where cols. 1&2 match cols 2&3 in list 2):

```
With[{s1 = #1[[All, #3]], s2 = #2[[All, #4]]},
   Pick[#1, 
    Replace[s1, 
     Dispatch[
      Append[Thread[Rule[Intersection[s1, s2], True]], _ -> 
        False]], {1}], True]] &[list1, list2, {1,2}, {2,3}]
```

Should be comparable in speed to original (perhaps a tiny bit slower), and can be used on single columns also (same format as prior).

Not clear on part 2 requirements, might you give an example?

I *think* you're after something like this (in this example, giving list 1 where cols 1,2, and 3 do *not* match any of the sets of cols 2,3, and 4 in list 2):

```
With[{s1 = #1[[All, #3]], s2 = #2[[All, #4]]},
   Pick[#, 
    Replace[s1, 
     Dispatch@
      Append[Thread[Rule[Complement[s1, s2], True]], _ -> 
        False], {1}]]] &[list1, list2, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}]
```

Note I used `Complement` to do the selection *en masse* - this is equivalent to `!MemberQ[<cols of list 2>, <element of cols of list 1>]` mapped over the elements, but *much* faster. Let me know if that's the intent.

The same can be had simply reversing the pick condition with the intersection:

```
With[{s1 = #1[[All, #3]], s2 = #2[[All, #4]]},
   Pick[#1, 
    Replace[s1, 
     Dispatch[
      Append[Thread[Rule[Intersection[s1, s2], True]], _ -> 
        False]], {1}], False]] &[list1, list2, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}]
```

*Might* be a little faster - have not tested...